# How to encode data for a semi-supervised Adversial Autoencoder (AAE)?

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to recreate the model described in section 5 of [the AAE paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05644.pdf).

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding the architecture of the encoder so I could incorporate both the input image and the class label and get the correct latent output for both.

Currently I have an encoder that simply separates the two as follows:

```
    def build_encoder(self):

    input_img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
    input_class = Input(shape=self.num_classes,)
    """ Features first"""
    encoder_f = Flatten()(input_img)
    encoder_f = LSTM(512, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(encoder_f)
    encoder_f = LSTM(512, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(encoder_f)
    # For feature extraction
    features = Dense(self.latent_dim, activation='linear')(encoder_f)
    """ Then labels"""
    encoder_c = Flatten()(input_class)
    encoder_c = LSTM(8, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(encoder_c)
    encoder_c = LSTM(8, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(encoder_c)
    # For signal classification
    classes = Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax')(encoder_c)  

    return Model([input_img, input_class], [classes, features])
```

But it doesn't sit quite right with me, and I don't think that's what the authors intended. Can I simply run both the flattened input image and label vector through the same encoder like

```
    imgs= Flatten()(input_img)
    labels = Flatten()(input_class)
    encoder = LSTM(512, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(imgs)(labels)
    encoder = LSTM(512, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))(encoder)

    features = Dense(self.latent_dim, activation='linear')(encoder) 
    classes = Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax')(encoder)

    return Model([input_img, input_class], [classes, features])
```

And get the correct latent output?

**EDIT:**
On a closer reading, section A.2.1 of the original paper describes the encoder architecture:

> The q(y|x) and q(z|x)
>   share the first two 1000-unit layers of the encoder. The dimensionality of both the style and label
>   representation is 10. On the style representation, we impose a Gaussian distribution with the standard
>   deviation of 1. On the label representation, we impose a Categorical distribution

This implies that my original implementation was not correct, but the alternative of running both inputs through the same encoding layers is.

Comment: Is there any relation between $p_d$ and $p$ here?